# How to access console in Eufloria HD?

Tags: cheats, eufloria

I can't figure out how to access the console menu in Eufloria HD from the Humble Bundle. Every time I press <kbd>~</kbd>, the console opens up but I can't type into it. I've already tried putting "-console" into the shortcut's target property

Comment: Are you sure it *has* a console?

Comment: I supose you've tried this http://www.cheathappens.com/show_board2.asp?headID=89645&titleID=15879

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do NOT try this if you haven't played the game yet. Eufloria is a wonderful game and should be experienced in the way that is intended, not in the way of cheating.**

To cheat, first enable the console by adding "-console" parameter without quotes to the game's shortcut.

In game, first press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and nothing will happen. Then press <kbd>F4</kbd> to change faction visibility as well as camera lock.

Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to get desired asteroid ID.

Use <kbd>~</kbd> to call out the console, and enter
a = GetAsteroid(Asteroid ID)

and check that you are indeed the owner of this asteroid: 
a.owner

this value is 1 for player. Don't panic if it shows error, clean out the input field and try again.

Note: Pause your game before entering any of the following cheats. I have found that sometimes the commands would accelerate time in the game, i.e. everything is faster, way faster for some computers to handle I'm afraid.

- To add seedlings: a:AddSeedlings(integer)
- To add enhanced seedlings: a:AddSuperSeedlings(integer)
- To modify max number of trees allowed: a.TreeCap = integer
- To add and level up a tree: s = a:AddDysonTree() s:LevelUp() s = a.AddDefenseTree() s:LevelUp()
- To add a flower to a tree: (you have to have a name previously
  designated to the tree, currently I can't find any method to select
  an existing tree.) s = a:AddDysonTree()    s:LevelUp() s:LevelUp()
  s:LevelUp() flower = s:AddFlower()    flower:GrowToMax()
- To add a LASER MINE!!: (laser mines are, in the game's view, flowers
  of the defense tree.) s = a.AddDefenseTree() s:LevelUp() s:LevelUp()
  s:LevelUp() flower = s:AddFlower() flower:GrowToMax()

source: http://www.cheathappens.com/show_board2.asp?headID=89645&titleID=15879

Comment: Doesn't work on "Eufloria HD" on Steam ...